# Is there any way to embed a youtube video that is disabled to be embedded on sites?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to embed youtube videos that is disabled embedding by request on youtube. Perhaps by embedding them on a custom iframe or youtube-api?

The example video I am looking at is this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhG5ToCpNh4&feature=c4-overview-vl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://youtube.com/v/fhG5ToCpNh4/ in an iframe yields these attributes for the YT player:

```
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block;
```

Sorry but I think you are out of luck, the only known work-around for the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is to write a server-side proxy. Which in this case you may as well download the .flv and host it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If the restrictions are due to manually requesting that embedding is disabled, you can't get around that; that's the whole point of the restriction.